# Is it bad to ask questions regarding communication?

Tags: discussion, marketing

I was thinking about asking a question regarding communicating effectively, but I realized it may be not directly related to programmers. So, I will ask here.

Is it ok to ask questions on stackoverflow like:

"Is this fun prezi.com presentation effective at communicating the purpose behind ^caret:

http://prezi.com/w3aavx2irfru/

Is it more important to communicate an underlying idea rather than explicitly documenting the technology?"

Or, is it not a real question and considered project marketing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow is not the site for this.

Comment: I find that the #3 problem for programmers is communication, so can you elaborate?

Comment: @Math: It is not a question about programming. I find that programmers eat a lot of donuts, but that is not relevant either.

Comment: but effective communication is about programming since we have to deal with other people. Same as source control, source control is not about programming but programming on teams.

Comment: Delicious sandwiches are about programming since we have to eat them for precious blood sugar.

Comment: @Math: The fact that you have to argue this means it is not acceptable.

Comment: Good point. I was on the border.

Answer (score 7):

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) says:

> Oh yes, and it should be about
>   programming. You know, with a
>   computer.

The effect of a presentation seems out of scope.  It's related to programmers but not to programming.